# How can i used Volley and Loader in a single android project?

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-volley, loader

In my project first i am using **AsyncTask** to load the data in the **listView** from internet. After that i used Loader to load data from internet using **AsyncTaskLoader**. but now i find that volley is the better way to fetch data from internet. So my question is how to load data in loader using **Volley**? Currently i am display the data on listView with the help of loader but if i am not using loader to load the data so what are the alternative to load the data in listView using Volley?

Project URL: https://github.com/CSS08/InfiniteNews

Comment: Please include the code of your loader where you display the data - we can then suggest how you need to change this when using Volley.

Comment: Hey @ishmaelMakitla i added my project URL now i want to used volly to fetch the data so how i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Volley `StringRequest` for this purpose - you then parse the response `JSON` using the code you already have in your `QueryResolver` class. Please see the code sample below - this should give you some idea of how to use Volley for your purposes - you may decide where to put the code - I am only giving you some hints as to how you can achieve the use of Volley library.

```
try{
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);           
        StringRequest newsDataRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,url, new Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String newsDataJson) {                   
                Log.i(TAG, "Got News Articles From Server:: "+newsDataJson);
                //Now process the volley response using your QueryResolver code:
                List <NewsData> newsData = QueryResolver.extractFromJson(newsDataJson);
                //with the newsData - you can now update your adapter - I am using an example here
                 newsDataAdapter.clear();
                // If there is a valid list of {@link NewsData}s, then add them to the adapter's
                // data set. This will trigger the ListView to update.
                if (newsData != null && !newsData.isEmpty()) {
                    newsDataAdapter.addAll(newsData);
                }
            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //there was an error - you want to print it out here...
            }
        });
        //add the request to queue
        queue.add(newsDataRequest);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        //some issues here - 
    }
```

I hope this helps you. You can check here for a [basic Volley tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `AsyncTaskLoader`, that uses an `AsyncTask` to download in the background, you can write a class that extends `Loader<NewsData>` and in it's `onForceLoad()` method enqueue Volley requests, that will do the actual loading. Then in Volley's `onResponse` callback pass the result to Loader's `deliverResult` method. That way, you will keep all the benefits of a Loader and improve the networking performance.

Comment: Thank you i got it. can you please explain "Then in Volley's onResponse callback pass the result to Loader's deliverResult method." this line with coding.